# How to add bulk products by WP WooCommerce API

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, bulk, woocommerce-rest-api

I tried to add multiple product at once using WooCommerce API but I can't.
Can any one help me.

*I successfully added single product but I can't add multiple. (When we go with single product method for huge volume, it's take long time. that's why)*

I tried code posted below.

Reference doc:- https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/v3.html?php#create-update-multiple-products

End point URL:- https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/bulk

Data:-

```
{
  "create": [
    {
            "title": "Premium Quality22",
            "type": "simple",
            "regular_price": "77.99",
            "description": "This is First product description from Balamurugan Ayyasamy",
            "short_description": "This is First product description from Balamurugan Ayyasamy",
            "categories": [
              9,
              14
            ],
            "images": [
              {
                "src": "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/preview_1000-2009446955-2-547x365.jpg",
                "position": 0
              },
              {
                "src": "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/preview_1000-2009446955-2-547x365.jpg",
                "position": 1
              }
            ]
    },
    {
            "title": "Premium Quality2",
            "type": "simple",
            "regular_price": "34.99",
            "description": "This is second product description from Balamurugan Ayyasamy",
            "short_description": "This is second product description from Balamurugan Ayyasamy",
            "categories": [
              9,
              14
            ],
            "images": [
              {
                "src": "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/preview_1000-1928542175.jpg",
                "position": 0
              },
              {
                "src": "http://dev.datanetiix.com/orange_coast/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/preview_1000-1928542175.jpg",
                "position": 1
              }
            ]
    }
  ]
}'
```

I got this response when tried with postman (When I am tried using PHP curl function same result)

```
{
    "code": "rest_no_route",
    "message": "No route was found matching the URL and request method.",
    "data": {
        "status": 404
    }
}
```

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/coderest_no_routemessageno-route-was-found-matching-the-url-and-reque/#post-11194479

Answer (score 0):

You're using the outdated WooCommerce API reference. Try to use this endpoint instead:

https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#batch-update-products